# Python to publish to Microsoft Teams Chat

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have been playing with the Python API to publish to MS teams. Worked out how to publish to a channel - it is quite easy. Is it possible to publish to a Chat group however?

Happy to publish to a channel and republished to a chat channel if that is possible.

MORE INFO:
This script works via SQL server. The message appears in the Channel associated with the webhook.

```
declare @script nvarchar(max) = N'
import pymsteams
myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard("webhook as generated by Teams")
myTeamsMessage.text("Testing From SQL Server")
myTeamsMessage.send()
'

execute sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python', @script = @script
```

The process is that from a channel in teams you use the connector to generate the webhook via the Configure button
[image]

However no such functionality exists as far as I can tell to do the same from a Chat group, hence the question above.

As indicated above, I would be happy for teams to automatically repost from a Channel to a Chat group, but not sure how to make this happen.

Comment: Could you please provide more details what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Please provide more detail on how you're publishing currently to a channel, so that we can provide a better answer in context. Are you using a Microsoft Graph API for Python, or something like that?

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: You can subscribe to [chatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource to get notifications when any mesage gets posted in Team channel. Using that endpoint you can further send messages to [Group Chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

Comment: Thank you Prasad-MSFT. I will try and follow this when I get a chance.